# Solved: Adding new Column to ORM SQLAlchemy table in a volatile setting

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am working on a open source persistance layer for a MQTT-Broker https://github.com/volkerjaenisch/amqtt_db

Incoming MQTT messages are irregular blobs of data so usually the DB-Backend is some kind of object storage.

I do it the hard way and deserialize the blobs into typed data colums and store them into a fast relational database. My finally target will be timescaleDB but first I go via SQLAlchemy to access a wide bunch of DBs with one API.

MQTT messages are volatile (think not always complete) so the DB scheme has to adjust dynamically e.g. adding new columns for new information.

```
First Message:
Time: 1234
Temperature : 23.4

Second Message:
Time: 1245
Temperature : 23.6
Rel Hum : 87 %
```

I have used SQLalchemy ORM for more than a decade but always for quite static databases. So I am new to work dynmically.

Utilizing the ORM to build DB tables dynamically from the structure of incoming MQTT-Messages was quite doable and worked out perfect.

But currently I am stuck with the case of additional information in the MQTT-Packages that extends the tables with new columns.

What I did so far:

Utilizing sqlalchemy-migration it was quite easy to dynamically add new columns to the existing table in the DB. In the code "topic_cls" is the declarative class and "column_def" a col_name - type mapping.

```
from migrate.versioning.schema import Table as MiTable, Column as MiColumn
    
def add_new_colums(self, topic_cls, column_def):
    table_name = str(topic_cls.__table__.name)
    table = MiTable(table_name, self.metadata)
    for col_name, col_type in column_def.items():
        col = MiColumn(col_name, col_type)
        col.create(table)
```

Works like a charm. But how to get this changes to the DB reflected back into declarative classes? I tried to get a new inspection of the table:

```
new_table = Table(topic_cls.__table__.name, self.metadata, autoload_with=self.engine)
```

This also works but it gives me a new table but not a declarative base.

So my stupid questions are:

1. Is this the right way to achive my goal?
2. How can I get a declarative class by inspecting an already existing table in a DB?

"Drop the ORM and use SQL" is not the answer I am looking for.

Cheers,
Volker

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution but it is a bit of a hack.

```
new_table = Table("test/topic_growth", Base.metadata, autoload_with=self.engine)

Base.metadata.remove(topic_cls.__table__)

new_dcl = type(str(table_name), (Base,), {'__table__': new_table})

Base.metadata._add_table(table_name, None, new_table)
```

After you obtained the new table via inspection, remove the old table entry from the metadata.
Then generate a new declarative base with the new table and same table name.
At last add the new table to the metadata.